# Need help creating a Doubly Linked-List from Scratch in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to implement an selfmade Doubly LinkedList using Strings as data(but i am
testing most of the times with numbers so don´t get confused) i tried it without using dummy nodes. I am implementing an interface (with the given methods) which is not neccessery for the question and two classes: StringLinkedList for the methods and Node for the Nodes. I have two methods i struggle with.

**First issue** i have is with the add(int index, String value)-method(adding String at certain index). For some reason it mixes all the numbers up for example:

I first add these Strings:

```
s.add("1");
s.add("2");
s.add("3");
s.add("4");
s.add("5");
s.add("6");
s.add("7");
s.add("8");
s.add("9");
s.add("10");
```

so the order would be 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 and then i mix them up with these Strings:

```
s.add(0, "a");
s.add(1, "b");
s.add(1, "c");
s.add(1, "d");
s.add(2, "e");
s.add(3, "f");
```

So now the order is -> d e f c b a 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10;

.-i expected it to be -> a d e f c b 1 2 3 4 5...

(Maybe it has something to do with my show()-method which prints all elements in order(i hope))

**So why does the "a"(index: 0) move with others along even if it is at index 0?**

**Second problem** i have with is the remove(int index)-method(removes String at specific index).

It also returns the removed String but the issue here is that sometimes it returns a wrong string

but removes the right one. The removing is not the problem here it is the wrong return value.

A little example:

I have these Strings 1 2 5 3 4 5 6 8 9 10
than i try to remove three Strings(first, last and one in the middle) with these lines of code

```
s.remove(0);   
s.remove(7);    
s.remove(s.remove(s.size());
```

it should be the number 1 8 and 10

but instead it shows 2 8 and 10

**Why does it not return 1 instead of the 2?**

If you know the answer, you would help me so bad!

```
    public class StringLinkedList implements StringList{
    
        private Node head;
        private int size;
        
    
        public class Node{
            String data;
            Node next;
            Node prev;
    
            public Node(Node prev, String data, Node next) {
                this.data = data;
                this.next = next;
                this.prev = prev;
            }
    
    
            public String getData() {
                return data;
            }
        }
    
        public StringLinkedList() {
            head = null;
            size = 0;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void add(String value) {
    
            if(head == null) {                          
                head = new Node(null, value, null);     
    
            }else {
                Node current = head;            
                while(current.next != null) {           
                    current = current.next;             
                }
                Node newNode = new Node(current, value, null);      
                current.next = newNode;
            }
            size++;             
    
        @Override
        public void add(int index, String value) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
            
            if(index <  0 || index > size()) {          
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();      
            }
            
            Node current = head;
    
            int i = 1;
            while(i < index) {      
                current = current.next;     
                i++;            
            }
    
            if(current.prev == null) {      
                Node newNode = new Node(null, value, current);          
                current.prev = newNode;     
                head = newNode;             
                
            } else if(current.next == null){
                Node newNode = new Node(current, value, null);      
                current.next = newNode;                             
                
            }else {
                Node newNode = new Node(current.prev, value, current);
                current.prev.next = newNode;        
                current.prev = newNode;         
            }
    
            size++;         
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean contains(String value) {
    
            Node current = head;            
    
            while(current != null) {        
                if(current.data.equals(value)) {        
                    return true;
                }
                current = current.next;
            }
    
            return false;
        }
    
        @Override
        public int indexOf(String value) {
    
            int index = 0;
            Node current = head;
    
            while(current != null) {    
                index++;                
                if(current.data.equals(value)) {    
                    return index;
                }
                current = current.next;
    
            }
            return -1;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean remove(String value) {
    
            Node current = head;
    
            while(current != null) {
    
                if(current.data.equals(value)) {
    
                    if(current.next == null) {          
                        current.prev.next = null;
                    }
    
                    else if(current.prev == null) {     
                        current = current.next;
                        current.prev = null;
                        head = current;
                    }
    
                    else {
                        current.prev.next = current.next;       
                        current.next.prev = current.prev;       
                    }
    
                    size--;
                    return true;
    
                }else {
                    current = current.next;
                }
            }
    
            return false;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String remove(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
    
            if(index <  0 || index > size()) {      
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
    
            Node current = head;
            int i = 1;
    
            while(i < index) {
                current = current.next;
                i++;
            }
    
            if(current.next == null) {          
                current.prev.next = null;
            }
    
            else if(current.prev == null) {     
    
                current = current.next;
                current.prev = null;
                head = current;
    
            }
    
            else {
                current.prev.next = current.next;       
                current.next.prev = current.prev;       
    
            }
            size--;
            return current.getData();
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public String get(int index) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
    
            if(index <  0 || index > size()) {      
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
    
            Node current = head;
            int i = 0;
    
            while(i < index) {
                current = current.next;
                i++;
            }
    
            return current.getData();
        }
    
        @Override
        public int size() {
    
            return size;
        }
    
        public void show() {
            Node current = head;
            while(current != null) {
                System.out.println(current.data);
                current = current.next;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Basically i have problems with inserting and deleting values of the first index

Comment: where do i need to update the head node?

Comment: It looks like your code is OK, except that | add() | needs a fix: | int i = 0; | . You could also change | while(i <= index){ | . With the current code, if caller's index value is `1`, the code inserts before index `0` instead of before index `1` . Yevgeniy has posted an answer explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

Your `add(int index, String value)` indexing logic is a bit confused:

- you insert at the head of the list when index is 0 or 1;
- in other cases your methods behave as if the list is indexed starting from 1, which is probably not intended;
- you insert before `current` element except if that `current` element is the last one, and in that case you insert after `current` element. Insertion should be consistent with regard to your index position in the list

Your `remove(int index)` has the same problem with mixing up index 0 and 1 and removing the head in both cases.

And be on the lookout for opportunities to improve your code and make it more concise, that usually also helps with debugging.

Comment: I kind of don´t understand how to jump to a certain node. I only started at 1 because otherwise it would give me a NullPointerException. It does not work with the while-loop. How can i fix this or is there another way to do it?

Comment: you’re already halfway there, think of it this way: when your index is 0 you’re working with ‘head’, when it’s 1 - with ‘head.next’, and so on and so on. Maybe start with a for loop and then change it to while loop when you get the hang of it. @rcgldr also left a helpful comment to your post, you can just change to ‘int i = 0’, just make sure you understand why it works

Comment: I understand what the problem is. I execute the same for index 0 and 1 but I don´t know how to write the code for the issue. I understood that if index is 0 it is head and everything else i work with head.next but how do i code this?